# apache and mod_proxy: How can i log which worker was selected?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, load-balancing, mod-proxy

we are runing an apache reverse proxy in front of several tomcats. sometimes we like to know to which server the request was forwarded. as we use mod_proxy_balancer.

i tried

```
 \"%{X-Forwarded-Server}i\"
```

but this doesn't work. it shows the name of my loadbalancer (apache)

How can i log which worker was selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e`.

There's a few other variables available for checking on the request routing, too; see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_troubleshooting).

Comment: great. i searched the documentation for this but was somehow not successful. thx.